# SQL-transact- alter column -char to datetime -103

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime-format

I need to convert a char column that looks like:

```
10/04/2012
23/01/2006
20/09/2006
20/09/2006
```

to datetime.

This works if I do:

```
Select  field, convert(datetime, [field], 103) from tablex
```

I get

```
10/04/2012  2012-04-10 00:00:00.000
23/01/2006  2006-01-23 00:00:00.000
20/09/2006  2006-09-20 00:00:00.000
20/09/2006  2006-09-20 00:00:00.000
```

But I need to do it in the alter table statement (I dont want to create another column and drop the previous one, it must be a way to do this in one step):

```
alter table tablex
alter column field datetime (103)
```

Error message:

> Column, parameter, or variable #27: Cannot specify a column width on
>   data type datetime.

How can I convert the field inside the alter table statement, or at least without creating another field and then dropping the previous one?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to first update your column to an unambiguous date format. `UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET YourColumn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,YourColumn,103),112)`. And then you can use your alter table directly: `ALTER TABLE... ALTER COLUMN YourColumn DATETIME`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The sample code make it seem like SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is convert the data in the column to be in US format first.  Then you can alter the column to be datetime without specifying the format.

Here's an example using a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #t ( col1 VARCHAR(50) ) 

INSERT INTO #t ( col1 ) VALUES ( '10/04/2012' ) 
INSERT INTO #t ( col1 ) VALUES ( '23/01/2006' ) 
INSERT INTO #t ( col1 ) VALUES ( '20/09/2006' ) 
INSERT INTO #t ( col1 ) VALUES ( '20/09/2006' ) 

UPDATE #t SET col1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, col1, 103 ))

ALTER TABLE #t ALTER COLUMN col1 DATETIME

SELECT col1 FROM #t

DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: "convert the data in the column to be in US format first" - it would appear from the question that it already is. Also, without knowing what settings are in force for the user, there's no guarantee that SQL Server will unambiguously convert from the US format anyway. At best, it *might* work. It middle, you get an error. At worst (all day values <= 12) it scrambles days and months.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly, that's why I posted a comment saying that it should convert it to an unambiguous format first.

Comment: The question shows "23/01/2006" that is clearly not US format.  If you have mixed formats then there is no way to know which format to convert to for example 4/12/2006 could be more than one format.